# Creating Word macro that can format selected image "In Front of Text"

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word, qr-code

I am currently making some device tags that utilize QR codes. The way that the tags are designed requires that I format the QR code image using the "In Front of Text" option. I have created simple macros for all other steps, but Word does not allow me to create a macro that selects Wrap Text formatting and then select In Front of Text.

Is there any way or code that I can use that allows me to select each QR code and format it with In Front of Text formatting?

Comment: Please explain "Word does not allow me to create a macro...". Exactly how does Word not allow creating the macro?

Comment: Sure. When I use the normal "Record a macro..." function built into Word, I can normally record a series of actions that I want to do to the QR codes. But for the newer tags that I am trying to create, I need to format the image using the "In Front of Text" option. Once I begin recording a macro, Word does not allow me to select any Wrap text formats as they are all greyed out.

Answer (score 3):

In order to set the text wrap of a Word `Shape` object to "In front of text" use the `WrapFormat.Type` property, setting the Type ot `wdWrapFormatFront`.

Sample code:

```
Dim shp As word.Shape
'' Works on the currently selected Shape
Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
'' If you know which Shape, by index or by Name, then
' Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(indexOrName)
'' If the object is currently an InlineShape it must first 
'' be converted to a Shape
' Set shp = InlineShapeObject.ConvertToShape 
shp.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapFront
```